# IP range for Europe? Detect with PHP?

Tags: php, geolocation

I am looking to implement the "Cookie Law" using PHP and JavaScript. I think it is pointless to have users from other continents fill out the form when they open up my site but it is unfortunately required for EU.

I tried searching for IP range for europe and I came up with nothing.

I know I can use explode() and $_SERVER['remote_addr'] and substr() to isolate the specific IP range the problem I am facing is what IPs to blacklist i.e. 194.XXX.XXX.XXX - 198.XXX.XXX.XXX?

Also, what would be the best way to implement this, would using if else statements work? I mean if the user is in europe, display some JS and if the user is in another display some other JS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as an "IP range for Europe". What there are are thousands of subnets allocated to ISPs who trade in Europe, most of them no wider than /20. If I were you I would use an existing IP locator service.

Comment: @DaveRandom ok, my website is based on php, so how would I implement that?

Comment: [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ip+locator+api) ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom hmmm... google, I really hate using js :D thanks for the reply, I would have loved for there to be a solution in PHP though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a GeoLocation Database to check for the Country using the REMOTE_ADDR in PHP.

There is for example [GeoLite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite) which offers a PHP [API Library](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$country = file_get_contents("http://api.wipmania.com/".$ip."?[YOUR SITE URL]");

$eu_countries = array("BE", "BG", "CZ", "DK", "DE", "EE", "IE", "EL", "ES", "FR", "HR", "IT", "CY", "LV", "LT", "LU", "HU", "MT", "NL", "AT", "PL", "PT", "RO", "SI", "SK", "FI", "SE");

$checked = in_array(strtoupper($country), $eu_countries);
```